# Azure Authorization code flow with PKCE doesn't work with confidential client (web app client type)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, pkce

I have the following setup: angular app -> auth server -> azure ad.
I registered auth server as a confidential client(web app) in Azure.
I use the following code to connect the Azure ad:

```
.AddAbpOpenIdConnect(configuration["OpenIdConnect:AuthenticationScheme"], configuration["OpenIdConnect:DisplayName"], options =>
{
  options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] + "/v2.0/";
  options.ClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
  options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
  options.CallbackPath = configuration["AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
  options.ClientSecret = configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
  options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
  options.SaveTokens = true;
  options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
  options.Scope.Add("email");
  options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
  options.Prompt = OpenIdConnectPrompt.SelectAccount;
})
```

It works fine but uses Credential client flow.

I want to switch to Authorization code + PKCE flow. So I write the following:

```
.AddAbpOpenIdConnect(configuration["OpenIdConnect:AuthenticationScheme"], configuration["OpenIdConnect:DisplayName"], options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] + "/v2.0/";
    options.ClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.CallbackPath = configuration["AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
    // options.ClientSecret = configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
    options.Prompt = OpenIdConnectPrompt.SelectAccount;
    
})
```

And it doesn't work until I switch from the web app to the SPA app.

How to make it work with web app client type?

Answer (score 2):

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added redirect URI as **`web`**:

[image]

Now for ***sample***, I used the below endpoint to **authorize users via PKCE flow**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=Directory.Read.All
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

And the **auth-code** generated:

[image]

I tried to generate access token using below parameters, but it failed with **error**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:Directory.Read.All
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
code_verifier:S256
```

[image]

The error "***AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type***" usually occurs if PKCE flow is being used to connect to Azure AD using the application that is configured as web.

**To resolve the error**, I tried to switch the web app to SPA app:

[image]

After making the above changes, **I am able to generate access token** successfully:

[image]

> **Note** that: If the Azure AD Application is configured as **`web`** then you have to make use of Authorization code flow not PKCE flow, as PKCE flow works only for **`SPA`** applications.

For **Azure AD Application configured as web**, I used Authorization code flow:

I made use of below **endpoint to authorize users**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=Directory.Read.All
&state=12345
```

[image]

Now, I am able generate **access token** successfully:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:Directory.Read.All
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

> And it doesn't work until I switch from the web app to the SPA app.
> How to make it work with web app client type?

**Hence**, if you want your application to be configured as web only, then you have to make use of Authorization Code Flow instead of PKCE.

**To resolve the issue,** modify the code by setting `options.UsePkce = false` and by passing the client secret too:

```cs
.AddAbpOpenIdConnect(configuration["OpenIdConnect:AuthenticationScheme"], configuration["OpenIdConnect:DisplayName"], options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] + "/v2.0/";
    options.ClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.CallbackPath = configuration["AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
   options.ClientSecret = configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.UsePkce = false;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
    options.Prompt = OpenIdConnectPrompt.SelectAccount;
    
})
```

**Reference:**

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Comment: thank you for your effort, but that is exactly what I did and tried to explain in the question. Do you know why PKCE only works with SPA apps?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow. It's by default the PKCE flow flow for SPA apps. PKCE is used to protect the authorization code flow in mobile apps.

Comment: For web app according to Microsoft it works for auth code flow only.